# ASP.Net Machine.Config Transformations

Tags: machine.config, web-config-transform, visual-studio-setup-proje, xslt

I am creating a strongly signed class library that contains an ASP.Net HttpModule and HttpHandler.

I have created a visual studio setup project for my library that installs the library in the GAC, however i want to add an assembly reference and the HttpModule and HttpHandler to the machine.config of the destination machine of my Visual Studio Setup Project.

Before i go reinventing the wheel, is there an easy way to do this using the Visual Studio Setup project?

Answer (score 2):

My final solution was to:

- Create a commandline application that did everything i wanted it to do
- added my commandline app to the payload of my setup project
- ran the commandline app through custom actions in my setup project on "install" and "uninstall"

Someone may still be able to enlighten us on how this can be done using built in functionality.